# How do I navigate to another page when PHP script is done?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post

I have a simple POST script that I need to return to the page that was doing the Posting.

Is there any way to do it like this?

```
if($done)
    {
        //go to page
    }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if ($done)
{
    header("Location: /url/to/the/other/page");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you do NOT output anything before this. If you output anything, this wont work.

Comment: I can't seem to comment on Jordan's answer, so here is my comment as a separate answer. Jordan's approach will work, but you cannot include any `echo`, `print`, or plain HTML before you put the call to header. In general, this means that you should put your 'should I redirect' logic above any output. This makes sense -- why send data for a webpage if you're just going to redirect anyway? If you absolutely have to, though, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to try to get around this restriction.

Comment: @Sarwar: or you could enable output buffering ;-) (though I feel just adhering to the "don't output anything before this line" makes more sense myself)

Comment: technically you should use the full url, not the relative one, but i have never seen relative  fail

Comment: @Dagon Why should you use the full URL?

Comment: @alex because the manual says so :-), see the note in the manual page for header()

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but its just a bunch of MySQL queries before the logic.

Comment: Keep in mind that error traces may also prevent the redirect from happening (e.g., in case one of your queries fails).