# Open another page in php

Tags: php, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect)

how do i redirect to another page in php, once a process is finished.

for example my `<form>` tag sets the action attribute to "process.php". After the process on process.php is finished i want it to redirect to the site it cam from. how is that done?

Comment: Dup of [PHP page redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect), [How do I navigate to another page when PHP script is done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643697/how-do-i-navigate-to-another-page-when-php-script-is-done)

Comment: As a general comment: HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to `Location`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
if(processing == success) {
  header("Location:filename");
  exit();
}
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php
    header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Just make sure nothing is actually written to the page prior to this code, or it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like `header( 'Location: /my-other-page.html' );` to redirect. You can't have sent any other data on the page before you do this though.

Answer (score 2):

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' );
```

in your process.*php* file

Comment: also don't forget to call "exit" right after.